# Information about Home Primes

Tags: prime-numbers, advice

I will be doing some research on Home Primes and the lack of resources online baffled me. I would be grateful and thankful to those who contribute to this post adding their prior knowledge , links, facts and information about Home Primes.

I can then also add these information to the common sites such as wolfram and wikipedia to make others access knowledge quicker.

Also if anyone knows, why is there a huge mystery and vagueness in the research of home primes?

For anyone who does not know what a Home Prime is:

A Home Prime is the terminating prime in a sequence in concatenating the prime divisors of a number.

This may sound very abstract but an example will do

lets take 49
49 = 7x7 therefore we write it as 77
77 = 7x11 therefore we write it as 711
and we continue until we find a prime
since if we hit a prime we cannot factorise it any longer, the sequence ends and that prime is called a home prime.

Comment: Probably because it is not quite an interesting concept/function. Most questions about primes don't have answers.

Comment: If you list out the definition of a Home Prime that would make it easier to gather resources.

Comment: Indeed, I've been doing Number Theory since God was a boy, and I never heard of "Home primes". What are they?

Comment: sorry everyone added conceptual information

Comment: It seems that a "home prime" is exactly a prime whose base-10 representation can be split to create a nondecreasing sequence of primes. (I'm assuming "nondecreasing" since $77$ yields $711$ and not $117$.) This is a concept that can be investigated without actually calculating any concatenate-prime-divisors sequences.

Comment: The dynamic of this process is huge ! We have to factor each occuring number which soon will lead to pratical limits. Factordb allows to create and check such sequences, the case $n=49$ is apparently currently open.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_prime  the mersennewiki got taken down at one point

Comment: The sequence beginning with $49$ is carried out to $119$ terms at https://oeis.org/A056938/b056938.txt and reference is made to http://www.worldofnumbers.com/topic1.htm and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_prime and https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HomePrime.html and the links from those pages.

Comment: Have you had a look at those links, Mefecig? Do they help any?

Comment: Yes, thank y'all very much. Me and my friend are now trying to find some relations such as ratio's, uniqueness etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just my opinion, but Home Primes started out as recreational math. But you'll find there's likely no known shortcut for calculating what it will be from the start number.  Thus it relies on the toughness of factoring. You can get a few hints about factors by modular arithmetic, but it's not really that much help ... attempting to work backwards doesn't help much more ...

Answer (score 0):

I am currently generating home primes for numbers up to 5000000. Just for fun!
I stop the loop normally when the composite reaches 84+, but I have found several larger ones. I have some statistics. About 83% of all home primes are found at this point. Currently I have reached 3000000, 4000000 will be reached witin weeks. All factoring is done using MSIEVE 1.53. If anybody is interesded, I can mail a database as a .csv file as well a statistics file.

Comment: Hello, sorry for replying so late. Just wanted to know how the research is going and are 83% of homeprimes between 0 and 5000000 or of ALL homeprimes are found?